# Several rows in SQL Developer but VB says no rows

Tags: sql, vb.net, listview

```
    Dim Test123 As String
    Dim Conn As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Private")
    Conn.Open()
    Dim mySelectQuery As String = "SELECT mti_part_no,sum(mpcs.shop_inv_history.quantity) As FebQTY from mpcs.shop_inventory, mpcs.shop_inv_history where mpcs.shop_inv_history.date_time Like '%Feb% %2015%' AND comments = 'CHECK ITEM OUT' AND mpcs.shop_inventory.si_key=mpcs.shop_inv_history.si_key AND SHOP_INVENTORY.CATEGORY BETWEEN 900 and 999 AND SHOP_INVENTORY.SCRAP_FLAG <> 1 group by mti_part_no order by FebQTY DESC"
    Dim CMD As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(mySelectQuery, Conn)
    Dim Myreader As OleDbDataReader
    Myreader = CMD.ExecuteReader()
    Myreader.Read()
    Test123 = Myreader("FebQTY")
```

There are 180 rows when I copy/paste my query into SQL Developer, however whenever I try to use this in VB.NET to populate my `listview`, I was getting nothing. So I tossed it into the above code just to see what I was quickly getting back from `FebQTY` and the error is that there are no rows, same with `mti_part_no`.  Can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Sounds like a permissions issue. I would double check you are authenticating with the same account in both instances.

Comment: All my other queries to the same tables are working fine.  But I checked anyways, and its all good.  I've been working with SQL for months lately on this app and I've run into a lot of things I've had to learn and figure out but this one here has me completely stumped.

Comment: Anyone have any other suggestions?  Are there any VB.NET constraints or things I have to do on the VB side that would make it where a statement copied and pasted from SQL Dev to VB works on one but not the other?